# Eclipse: copy the selected snippet automatically

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way in Eclipse to automatically copy a snippet when we select it?

Comment: Do you mean without using Ctrl+C or the Edit or right-click menus?

Comment: Yes. Without using CTRL+C. When we select a text, it should copy the selected item automatically. In this way, We can avoid hitting CTRL+C.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following tool. It will automatically copy selected text (not only from Eclipse) to your Clipboard.

[AutoClipX](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Clipboard/AutoClipX.shtml)